# xsl:character-map / xsl:output-character do not work

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to use character transformation for my app. As example I looked at book and tried to play with example (if that matter [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527217) **Appendix A -> `[2.0] <xsl:character-map>`** section)

Here is my XML (from the book):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- special-characters.xml -->
<char-test>
    <tabs>
    public class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello, World!");
            }
        }
    </tabs>
    <special-char>&#x2780;</special-char>
    <special-char>&#x2781;</special-char>
</char-test>
```

Here is my XSL (from the book):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- character-map1.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" use-character-maps="sample" />
    <xsl:character-map name="sample" use-character-maps="circles">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#x9;" string=" " />
    </xsl:character-map>
    <xsl:character-map name="circles">
        <xsl:output-character character="&#x2780;" string="&lt;img src='images/circle1.gif'
width='28' height='28'/&gt;" />
        <xsl:output-character character="&#x2781;" string="&lt;img src='images/circle2.gif'
width='28' height='28'/&gt;" />
    </xsl:character-map>
    <xsl:template match="char-test">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>A test of some special characters</title>
            </head>
            <body style="font-family: sans-serif;">
                <h1>A test of some special characters</h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tabs">
        <pre style="font-size: 150%; font-weight: bold;">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </pre>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="special-char">
        <p style="font-size: 200%;">
            <xsl:text>Here's a special character: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I not expect to get ➀ and ➁ , I expect to get replacements for these characters. I tried http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html with above XML and XSL.

Result is not what I expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>A test of some special characters</title>
   </head>
   <body style="font-family: sans-serif;">
      <h1>A test of some special characters</h1>
      <pre style="font-size: 150%; font-weight: bold;">public class HelloWorld {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Hello, World!");
                }
            }</pre>
      <p style="font-size: 200%;">Here's a special character: ➀</p>
      <p style="font-size: 200%;">Here's a special character: ➁</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

special characters weren't replaced. I'm confused since these examples are from the nice book moreover I can see the same approach on the Web. 
Where is the magic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This suggests to me that the XSLT processor you're testing with is a version 1.0 processor rather than version 2.0 - character maps are a 2.0-only feature.

http://xsltransform.net/ supports 2.0 if you use the Saxon 9 engine.

Comment: Another possibility that would account for the symptoms is that you were using an XSLT 2.0 processor, but weren't using its serializer (e.g., you were sending output to a DOM tree)